# Add new Label and Textfield on button click

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm writing a program that has a `JPanel` containing `JLabel`s and `JTextField`s. I want to add a new line of `JLabel`s and `JTextField`s when a button is clicked.
I tried this code but it does not work.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JTextField txt= new JTextField();
    jPanel2.add(txt);
    jPanel2.validate();
    jPanel2.repaint();

}
```

Comment: it doesn't add anything..

Comment: It surely adds something, maybe you don't see it. Consider adding an example http://sscce.org

Comment: those code lines are correct, nothing cleaver without an SSCCE

Comment: What layout manager is `jPanel2` using?

Comment: i drag drop components instead of creating them in code, so i'm not sure if i can set a layout that way..doesn't make sense to design a GUI then set layout..

Comment: oh nvm i figured out how to set a Grid layout outside code

Comment: now it adds just fine, but i still have a problem with layout properties..will figure it out myself, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you need to add `JToolBar`. New line of objects and text is not so beautiful rather than if you place it at the head of the frame an make it visible to everyone.

Comment: actually that's a good idea , i already did it by adding new lines but the JToolBar sounds more neat, thank you